# Algebras generated by finite group semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reviewing for my algebra exam, and I have the following practice problem. Let $K$ be a field of characteristics $0$, and $R$ a $K$-algebra. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the unit group of $R$ that generates $R$ as a vector space. We want to show that $R$ is semisimple as a ring.

I tried to prove artinian and compute Jacobson radical, but that seems impossible. Should I try to use Artin-Wedderburn? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That it is Artinian is obvious, since it's a finite dimensional $K$ algebra. The general statement of this is known as Maschke's theorem. Maybe you can get some inspiration from its proof?

Comment: @rschwieb Since we have $G$ generates $R$ as a vector space, can we conclude $K[G]=R$? In that case, we can deduce the desired result using Maschke's theorem directly.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think you get an isomorphism, since the assumption was only that the set generates the algebra, not that it is a basis (as an example, the assumptions are satisfied by the set $\{-1,1\}$ in $K$ itself).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, that's the rub.  I was thinking basis :(. But given that every quotient of a semisimple ring is semisimple, I think he can still solve it with the comment above.  So yes to be clear, I should not have said it is an isomorphism in the comment above. But luckily since $K[G]$ is semisimple, so is its image $R$.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion mapping $G\to U(R)$ extends to an algebra homomorphism $K[G]\to R$. The assumption that the image of $G$ generates $R$ means this homomorphism is onto.

If you agree $K[G]$ is semisimple by Maschke, then also its quotient algebra $R$ is semisimple.